# Is there a way to pass the Title of a parent item to the create form inside a Child list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, lookup-column, list-form

We have 2 custom lists inside our sharepoint online team site:-

1. Dept list.
2. Employee list. this list has a lookup column to the Dept list. so inside the Employee Create & Edit forms, there will be a lookup list to chose the Dept item as follow:-

[image]

but i am trying to achieve this:-

1. when i access the Dept item's display form, to add a link name " + Add Employee"as follow:-

[image]

2. when we click on the "+ Add Employee" link, the Create form for the Employee list will be rendered with the current Dept title being automatically selected inside the Dept list? is this possible to do? if the answer is Yes then and how i can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think you can with modern lists, but with classic I'd say add a query string to the newform.aspx to handle setting values. The customization of New/Edit forms have been suggested in uservoice.

Comment: @Mike so you mean inside the "+ add employee" link I will need to pass the Dept title inside the URL, and then inside the new.aspx form i will need to retrieve the dept title from the url and populate the drop-down? if this is what you mean ? if the answer is yes, then in this case I need to modify the display.aspx form to add the link + I need to modify the Create.aspx form to retrieve the dept title from the url and populate the dropdown list. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mike .. Second question. now as you mentioned that customizing list forms is not possible in modern experience.. So is it a wrong approach if I chose to disable modern experience for the Dept & employee lists to allow me to implement the requirements?

Comment: I'd move forward with Modern experience. Modern Experience is what's getting updates and has plenty more to offer with Flow/PowerApps and other integrations. Classic is a dying breed, but the modern experience has so much to cover (SharePoint is huge) the MSFT SP team is basically writing 15 years of SharePoint development within the past several years with modern experience, so obviously, there is going to be a backlog of things missing.

Comment: @Mike thanks for your reply. so what is your suggestion to implement my requirements in this case? as modern interface does not allow me to customize the Dept's display form to add the "+ Add Employee " link + modern interface does not allow me to customize the create form for my Employee list, to be able to get the Dept title from the url and populate the Dept drop-down list with it.

Comment: now we are in 2018, and if i mention to my customer that we can not implement these 2 customization, then if i were them i would not be happy at all...now if modern interface allow us to customize its list forms for sure i will go with it, but currently we can not .... and i am not planning to disable modern interface for my whole site. i will just do this for the Dept & Employee lists..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic mode this can be done using something like the parent child setup by Mark Rackley, [link](http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26), however I have not seen it for modern lists

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the link you provide. but my concern in this case, if you see any harm of disabling the Modern experience for our Dept and Employees lists to be able to implement the parent/child relation ? in other works; in sharepoint online should we try not to invest in classic experience ?? .. the issue that currently modifying lists forms is not possible inside modern experience, while customizing list forms in classic experience is very powerful as we can add script and html the way we want..but my concern is about the Future-Proof of the classic experience ??

Comment: As a rule of thumb I very much prefer to avoid depricated functionality, like classic lists. However in some cases there is no alternative right now, and I have confidence that MS will not disable classic list mode any time soon. So the question really is whether your end users will be confused when they see the classic mode on one and the modern on another? (onless you switch to classic on the tenant, which I can not recommend)

Comment: Currently we already have a mix of classic and modern interfaces. as we have a lot of Enterprise wikis sites and those sites still do not have modern interfaces. also i do not think classic experience is actually deprecated, as in this link https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Classic-mode-support-timeline/td-p/3640 MS have mentioned  "We will continue to support both of these mitigations until the modern library experience supports the same level of customization as the classic one and partners have had ample time to adapt their solutions to the new experience."

Comment: so i think at this stage  i will go with the option to modify the Dept display form to add the "+ Add Employee" link + i will modify the Employee Create form to capture the Dept title from the URL and populate the Dept drop-down lookup list.. but i am keen to get ur feedback on this? thanks

Comment: It is proven solution so why not. Yes, it will have to be reimplemented some years from now, but that applies to lots of software

Answer (score 0):

You would need to customize SharePoint list forms with PowerApps. This is totaly doable in modern lists as well but with PowerApps.

Comment: but currently we do not have powerApps license for the users.. so i will need to customize the lists forms and use the classic experience .. so is this fine?